# null pointer exception for custonlistadapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

```
public class ListPage extends ListActivity
{
    TheLists a[] = new TheLists[1];
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_page);

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {

        class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TheLists>
        {
            MyAdapter()
            {
                super(ListPage.this, R.layout.list_row, R.id.sname, a);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);

                TextView name,category,id;

                name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sname);
                category=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.scategory);
                id=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sid);
                name.setText(a[0].schemelist[position]);
                category.setText(a[0].categorylist[position]);
                id.setText(a[0].idlist[position]);
                return(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a runtime error which says

```
05-02 18:56:32.224: E/AndroidRuntime(775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 18:56:32.224: E/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 18:56:32.224: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.example.listinflator_demo.ListPage$MyAdapter.getView(ListPage.java:75)
05-02 18:56:32.224: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
```

what changes are needed ?

Comment: Whatever is on line 75 that's null shouldn't be.

Comment: Dave is right. Which is 75th line?

Comment: There could be several issues: a is null, element at position 0 in a is null, schemelist, categorylist, idlist or the elements at their position are null.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, there is something very strange :

you pass a as a parameter to super. But a isn't initialized, never. Where do you get this value from ?

Anyhow, I suggest that you understand better want a [null pointer exception means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/693752). You will meet this kind of error quite often when programming in java, you would be better understanding how to find and correct them by yourself, it's more interesting than just getting your question answered.

Comment: public class TheLists
    {
 public String[] schemelist = {"SCHEME 1", "SCHEME 2", "SCHEME 3", "SCHEME 4", "SCHEME 5", "SCHEME 6", "SCHEME 7", "SCHEME 8", "SCHEME 9", "SCHEME 10"};;
 public String[] categorylist = {"subsidy", "loan", "scholarship", "subsidy", "loan", "scholarship", "subsidy", "loan", "scholarship", "loan"};
 public String[] idlist = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
 public String[] nulllist = {};
    }

'a' is an object of this "TheLists" class. This maybe a little stupid but there is no 75th line !

Comment: printout every value mentionned by @luxer. System.out.println( "a is" + a); At the beginning of your method, print variables before using them. Or learn how to debug. For sure there is a line 75 in your class ! Also, please note that an inner class is defined inside a class, not inside one of its methods.